# How to extend HTMLButtonElement using @angular/elements

Tags: angular, angular-elements

Trying to compile a component using `@angular/elements`. Seems `NgElement` always extends `HTMLElement`. But I would like to extend `HTMLButtonElement` instead. Been looking at the `createCustomElement`'s `strategyFactory` option, but cannot see where I can customize it.

Registering component like this:

```
const buttonComponent = createCustomElement(ButtonComponent, { injector } );
customElements.define('my-button', buttonComponent, { extends: 'button' });
```

Running this code throws the exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor: localName does not match the HTML element interface
```

Which is expected as `NgElement` always extends `HMTLElement`, anyone know a way to extend the `HTMLButtonElement` instead?